Prove that the eigenvalue of the Ricci tensor in a shrinking gradient Ricci soliton satisfies a differential inequality.
This question appears at the beginning of the short paper "Wang, J.P. and Munteanu, O., Positively curved shrinking
solitons are compact. J. Diff. Geom. 106 (2017) 499-505".
Suppose $(M, g)$ is a Riemannian manifold and $f$ is a smooth function on $M$. A triple $(M, g, f)$ is called a shrinking gradient Ricci soliton if it satisfies the following equation. $$\mathrm{Ric} + \nabla^{2}f = \frac{1}{2}g.$$
Suppose $(M, g, f)$ is a complete shrinking gradient Ricci soliton with nonnegative sectional curvature and positive Ricci curvature. Let $\lambda$ be the minimal eigenvalue of the Ricci tensor.
A basic result of the Ricci soliton is that the curvatuve of $(M, g, f)$ satisfies the following equation. $$\Delta_{f}R_{ij} = R_{ij} - 2R_{ikjl}R^{kl}.$$
Here $\Delta_{f}R_{ij} := (\Delta_{f}\mathrm{Ric})_{ij}$ and $\Delta_{f}T = \Delta T - \nabla_{\nabla f}T$ for all smooth covariant tensor field $T$ on $M$.
In the paper, it says that we can use the equation above to prove that $\lambda$ satisfies $$\Delta_{f}\lambda\leq \lambda$$ in the barrier sense. How can we prove this result?
My attempt
Fix $p\in M$. For any $v = v^{i}\partial_{i}\in T_{p}M$, we have
\begin{align*}
 v^{i}v^{j}\Delta_{f}R_{ij}
 & = R_{ij}v^{i}v^{j} - 2R_{ikjl}R^{kl}v^{i}v^{j} \\
 & = \mathrm{Ric}(v, v) - 2\mathrm{Rm}(v, \partial_{k}, v, \partial_{l})R^{kl}.
\end{align*}
Since $(M, g)$ has nonnegative sectional curvature and positive Ricci curvature, the matrix $(R^{kl})$ is positive definite and the matrix $(\mathrm{Rm}(v, \partial_{k}, v, \partial_{l}))$ is nonnegative definite. It follows that $\mathrm{Rm}(v, \partial_{k}, v, \partial_{l})R^{kl}\geq 0$ and $v^{i}v^{j}\Delta_{f}R_{ij}\leq \mathrm{Ric}(v, v)$.
If $v$ is an eigenvector of $\mathrm{Ric}$ with respect to the eigenvalue $\lambda(p)$ and $|v| = 1$, then $\mathrm{Ric}(v, v) = \left\langle v, \mathrm{Ric}(v)\right\rangle = \left\langle v, \lambda v\right\rangle = \lambda$. Hence we have $v^{i}v^{j}\Delta_{f}R_{ij}\leq \lambda$ at $p$.
But it seems that $v^{i}v^{j}\Delta_{f}R_{ij}$ has no relation to a $C^{2}$ function $\phi$ which satisfies the definition of a particular differential inequality in the barrier sense and I do not know what to do next.

Maybe extend $v$ to a smooth unit-length vector field $V$ in a neighbourhood and then study $\phi = \mathrm{Ric}(V,V)$?

Yes, I think this works - if you construct $V$ by parallel transport along rays then $\nabla V$, $\Delta_f V$ will vanish at $p$, and you should then be able to calculate $\Delta_f \phi = v^i v^j \Delta_f R_{ij}$ at $p$. By the way, it would be helpful to include the definition of $\Delta_f$ in your question.

@AnthonyCarapetis I carefully calculated and verified that this method is indeed correct. Thank you very much!

@AnthonyCarapetis Sorry. Recently, I have realized that I may not fully understand your process. May I ask for a detailed explanation of the definition of rays and why $\Delta_{f}V$ vanishes at $p$?
